# Cannot get month name properly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Trying to get the month names from JS Date() object, I got a duplicate of 'March' and no 'February'. How come? Here's my snippet:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    console.log(new Date(new Date().setMonth(i)).toLocaleString('en-us', { month: 'long' }));
}
```

Console output:

```
  January
2 March
  April
  May
  June
  July
  August
  September
  October
  November
  December
```

Thanks!

Comment: Because there is no 30th of February ...

Comment: Change the inner `new Date()` to `new Date('01/01')`  It will initialise the date object to 1st January before you set the month, and no longer rely on today's date.

Comment: Run it day after tomorrow ;)

Comment: February 30th is automatically corrected to March 1st.

Comment: @denys-séguret if it's random, this implies that you need to use your imagination. cheers

Comment: @Archer—don't do that. Parsing of strings is almost entirely implementation dependent. `new Date('01/01')` returns an invalid date in Safari and Firefox (and likely other hosts), the OP should use `new Date(2016,0)` (or any year that suits).

Answer (score 0):

If it is getting all the months of the year you are planning to do, then you have to set the date of all the dates you are creating to 1, because as today (as of the day this answer was sent) is 30th, there is no 30th of February that is why it is repeating march, so just set the date as 1 in your code and it should work fine,

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    console.log(new Date(new Date(new Date().setDate(1)).setMonth(i)).toLocaleString('en-us', { month: 'long' }));
}
```

ofcourse, the code will be getting quite messy with all the `new Date()`'s

Comment: Thanks! Alright, this defeats the purpose, month names are displayed properly, but the mess goes on when getting the number of days from a specific month and a specific year.

Comment: Or you could just write `new Date(2000, i, 1).toLocaleString(...)`.